# Is there a list of what open source software is installed with Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, open-source

is there a list available of what development tools are installed with Snow Leopard?

I can just go poking around and see what's installed in a haphazard way, but it would be helpful to have a document that says "Ruby 1.8.7 - (location), PHP 5.3 - (location), Python (etc.)."

This would include things like Web and database servers, too (I see Apache is there, and SQLite, but would like to have a complete list).

I checked the XCode 3.2 Release Notes and Installation Guide but couldn't find such a list, other than "UNIX Development Support" installed in /usr.

I'm doing this in advance of installing the typical stuff in the usual locations (instead of the default, proprietary arrangement without an indication of what's installed where).

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvotes. It's striking me as a relevant question: zee wants to get an idea of the infrastructure layout of Snow Leopard, so he can adapt his custom installations to what is "common" on the system. (Like you could install software virtually anywhere on a Windows box, but C:\Program Files is probably the best choice.) If you leave downvotes, at least leave comments on what you think is so bad about the Q.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, http://opensource.apple.com/

Choose a version of the OS ([10.6 for Snow Leopard](http://opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-106/)) and it every bit of open-source code used in that version - it shows what license it is under, has a source-code browser, and links to Apple's mirror of the code.

Answer (score 2):

It was a mistake carelessly dumping this question here from StackOverflow. Next time those doing the moving should read the question more carefully.

StackOverflow is for programmer questions and SuperUser is, by the site's own definition, for "computer enthusiasts."

Who's more likely to know what versions of Ruby, Python, Apache, MySQL, and other open source development tools are installed and where they're installed: a programmer or a computer enthusiast?

Thanks to dbr for the list above, though it doesn't specify the locations of the installed software. From the responses it seems such a list doesn't exist.

Comment: If you want to know where a specific cli program lives you can use the "which" command on the Terminal:

>

$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/) from Apple's site. Here's what it says, among other things:

> Mac OS X provides the most popular
>   open source development tools,
>   including the GNU Compiler Collection
>   (GCC), the GNU Debugger (GDB), make,
>   autoconf, and more.
>
> In addition to compiler tools, Mac OS
>   X also provides a large number of
>   scripting languages.
>
> Many of the compiler tools are
>   available under the GPL license.
>
> The following open source projects are
>   available via CVS: cygnus gcc gcc2 gcc3 gdb keymgr

And here are the scripting languages supported:

> Scripting languages harness the power
>   of the Unix command line. Mac OS X
>   includes the most popular open source
>   scripting languages ready to use out
>   of the box.
>
> The following shells and scripting
>   languages are available as open
>   source:
>
> awk bash ksh perl PHP (apache_mod_php)
>   python ruby sed (text_cmds) tcl tcsh
>   XSLT (libxslt) zsh

Some of these things come installed with XCode. You can find more information on the link above.